# Which size wire I need to run 220 volt breaker for a tanning bed

Tags: electrical

Which size wire do I need to run a 220 volt breaker? I need about 50 feet, but I'm not sure which size wire I need to run it with.  I know it's a 220 volt circuit breaker.

Comment: What is the amperage of the tanning bed?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the terminals are rated for 75°C, 4/0 conductors should handle 220 amperes @ 240 volts.

If the tanning bed doesn't actually pull 220 amperes (which I'm sure it doesn't). You should check the nameplate or manufacturer's installation instructions, to determine the actual electrical requirements.

Comment: What kind of outlet accommodates 4/0 conductors?  ;-)

Comment: @wallyk NEMA 14-220 devices, of course.  I figured a 220 ampere tanning bed would be hardwired, not cord connected.

Comment: @wallyk The plug looks like [this](http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/yvnjg8sxmbvgya1luf6n.jpg). Oh, wait... That's the [NEMA 20-400](http://www.macartney.com/what-we-offer/systems-and-products/connectivity/greenlink/greenlink-wetmate-11kv/).

Comment: Most of the beds I looked up had between 24 & 48 lamps. with high output  lamps the ballast I have draw just under .5 amps so the 220v service will probably be between 12 & 24 amps

Comment: Wow!  That is one gnarly connector!  11 kV at 400 amps!

Comment: Yeah that is one helluva tanning bed. You could probably tan from the next county.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this popped up near the top of the StackExchange app on my iPhone, I didn't realize it was this old and surely you have solved the problem, but since I went to the trouble of looking it up on the computer, I'll weigh in.

Choosing the appropriate wire size is of course about amperage, not voltage.

Tester101 is completely right about the 4/0 conductors handling 220 amps, and also about needing to check the nameplate on the tanning bed where it should list the electrical requirements (or look up the model in the service manual or on the web).

But 240 amps that's big enough service for your whole house (most likely). You obviously meant 240 Volts, not 240 amps.

You're obviously installing a dedicated circuit for the tanning bed.

Tanning beds I'm looking at online are all over the map in terms of power requirements. I don't see any specifying smaller than a 20A circuit or higher than a 70A circuit, so the wire size would be in line with this table:

```
20 amps   12 gauge copper
30 amps   10 gauge copper
40 amps    8 gauge copper
60 amps    6 gauge copper
70 amps    4 gauge copper
```

Here's an example of the receptacle requirements for various "Phoenix Sun" tanning bed models, with the hardwired ones requiring a permanently-wired connection into the box in the wall (no removable plug). Of course, each of these requires the equivalent rated breaker in the service panel. I just grabbed this at random--I don't know if I've ever even *seen* a Phoenix Sun tanning bed:

```
Tanning Bed Voltage Outlet

3000XP 220VAC, 20A NEMA 6-20R
4000XP 235VAC, 20A NEMA 6-20R
4000XP 1F 235VAC, 30A NEMA 6-30R
4000XP 2F 235VAC, 30A NEMA 6-30R
5000XP 235VAC, 30A NEMA 6-30R
5000XP 1F 235VAC, 30A NEMA 6-30R
5000XP 2F 235VAC, 30A NEMA 6-30R
6000VHR 235VAC, 30A NEMA 6-30R
6000VHR 1F 235VAC, 40A Hardwire
6000VHR 2F 235VAC, 40A Hardwire
8000STS 235VAC, 60A Hardwire
9000STS 235VAC, 70A Hardwire
9000STSXL 235VAC, 70A Hardwire
```